# pick up material from another object

Tags: unity, c#

is it possible to obtain a material from another object?
I'm trying everything and nothing, the only thing I could get was just the color of another object

```
public MeshRenderer takematerial;
public GameObject[] Objects;
for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Length; i++) {
    Objects [i].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = takematerial.material;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, just did a google, have you seen that one? https://answers.unity.com/questions/59355/change-the-material-on-an-object-in-a-script.html

Comment: The code you have there copies the material from the `takematerial` renderer and assigns it to each object in the `Objects` array. If that's not doing what you want, can you edit your question to add more detail about the observable symptoms by which this differs from what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reach or interact with the target object, by raycast, tag, collision, etc, it doesn't matter:

```
GameObject targetObj=GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");

Material targetMat = targetObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
//Creates  a copy of the first material of the object,unique to this renderer, if it had been a shared asset previously.

targetMat.color=Color.red; 
//Now targetMat referencing targetObjects renderer first material.
```